# When did server add listener to request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
        // some code here
    });

    request.addListener("end", function() {
        // some code here
    });
}).listen(8888);
```

As I know, in node, the anonymous function would execute when server received request. But in the sample code, the function would add listener to request which had received by server. However, it really works.

And my question is why it works. When did server add listener to request in node?

Comment: You might want to read more about Node's event loop.  E.g. https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop/

Comment: @Cully Thanks. I would check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what exactly which part of the process you're asking for help understand, but here's how your code works.

1. `http.createServer()` creates a server and the callback function you pass it is automatically registered as an event handler for the `request` event.
2. The `request` event calls it's callback with two arguments, the `request` and `response` objects.  The `request` object is of type `http.IncomingMessage` which implements the readable stream interface.
3. When the `request` callback is call, it executes `request.addListener('data', ...)` and this adds a listener for incoming data on the readable stream in the `request` argument.
4. So, as soon as data is available on that readable stream, it will call that listener with that chunk of data.  You can read a lot more about readable streams in the node doc to understand better how they work.
5. The listener for the `end` event tells you when the readable stream has finished giving you its data.

> When did server add listener to request in node?

This happens each time there is a new incoming http request to the server.  That's when the callback to the `http.createServer()` is called.  And, for each new incoming request, a new `http.IncomingMessage` object is created for that callback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. Actually, I am confused about the third and forth points. Had the `request` object received when the `request` callback is called? If `request` object had received, why `request.addListener('data', ...)` can work? Doesn't it add a listener for incoming data?

Comment: @Maxmengt - The argument passed to the callback on each incoming request is a request stream object.  It's a new object for each incoming request.  Because it's a stream object, one of the ways you can get the data from the stream is by registering a listener for the `data` event.  So, that's what `request.addListener("data", ...)` does.  If you don't know what streams are, then you will need to do some basic reading about streams before you will understand this.  A google search about node.js streams will turn up plenty of interesting articles.

Comment: @Maxmengt - FYI, for a `GET` request, there is nothing to stream (there's no body to the request - there's only the request URL).  The stream is generally used for POST requests where there's a body which could even be very large.

Comment: Thanks. I know now.